# Amazon S3 Folder Level Permissions Bucket policy NOT IAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I keep seeing posts that refer to setting a policy and while they mention S3 buckets the policy they are often referring to are IAM policies.

In my case I want to control access to my S3 bucket only by an actual "S3 **bucket policy**".

My current path is :::mybucket, which has /thing1/ and /thing2/

If I wanted a bucket policy that allows a CLI user the ability to list and get /thing1/* but not /thing2/* how would this be done? I've tried my policy with all kinds of conditions, paths etc but nothing seems to work...

Comment: Because there isn't such a thing, as far as I know.

Comment: If you wish to grant permissions to a specific user, you attach the policy directly to the IAM User, without using a Bucket Policy (which attaches to the bucket). Please edit your question to show us what you have tried, with a description of what is failing.

Comment: Two questions, what good is a bucket policy then? And what if you don’t ‘own’ the aws user?